# Displaying when a button is pressed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a RasberryPi3b and i am trying to simulate button presses on this device i have.
It is a START/STOP button system where STOP is always LOW, and START is LOW when pressed, as i understand.

I have some code that Displays when the start button is pressed, but stop button code doesn't print.
Below is the setup i have;

START & STOP - Connected to Ground;

START - Connected to GPIO14;

STOP - Connected to GPIO15;

And here is the code

```html
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
start_pins = [14]
stop_pins = [15]

for pin in start_pins:
  GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
  
for pin in stop_pins:
  GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
  
while True:
  for pin in start_pins:
    if GPIO.input(pin) == GPIO.LOW:
      print("Pin", pin," is low")
      
   for pin in stop_pins:
    if GPIO.input(pin) == GPIO.HIGH:
      print("Pin", pin," is high")
```

Once START is pressed it will also print "Pin 14 is low" multiple times, slightly confused why it prints so much.

Comment: If STOP pin 15 is always low, the condition `GPIO.input(15) == GPIO.HIGH` is never fulfilled.

Comment: But when pressed it will be high shouldnt it?

Comment: The infinite loop checks and prints as long as 14 is low.

Comment: Why did you wrote "It is a START/STOP button system where STOP is always LOW"?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh nevermind i changed GPIO.PUD_DOWN back to UP for stop pins.

And changed it to != for stop pins not ==